# child_process spawn have to control-c two times to exit when using exit-hook(process.on('SIGTERM'))

Tags: javascript, node.js, child-process

I have a program like this

```js
const { spawn } = require("child_process");
const exitHook = require("exit-hook");

exitHook(() => {
  console.log("Leaving");
});

spawn("my-program", ["my-args"], {
  stdio: "inherit"
}); // Long running server
```

Now, when I press `control-c` on my Mac, my terminal shows

```sh
Leaving
# Now, my terminal cursor is here, still now leaving the terminal
```

My terminal cursor hangs there, I have to press `control-c` once to actually leave the terminal.

```sh
Leaving
^C
```

Now I left, why is this happening?

I know exitHook use `process.on('SIGTERM')` and SIGINT internally.

How can I solve this? How can I press `control-c` only once to leave?

This only happened when I use child_process spawn.

Answer (score 0):

Try exiting the main process manually, or terminating the child process

```
exitHook(() => {
  console.log("Leaving");
  process.exit() 
  // or, 
  cp.exit()
});
const cp = spawn("my-program", ["my-args"], {
  stdio: "inherit"
}); // Long running server
```